# How to notify consumer once SpringBatch completes?

Tags: caching, spring-batch

I'm trying to cache few parameters in my consumer application as part of Spring Batch. During batch starts it should load the map , once batch completes it should clear the map. Is there any specific way in Spring this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `JobExecutionListener#afterJob` callback to clear the `Map` out.